# Heroku Buildpacks in Docker Images

Tags: node.js, docker, heroku, buildpack, jemalloc

I build my own docker images and run them on Heroku. This works just great, heres an example Docker file:

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ncc/web ./
CMD node ./index.js
```

The problem is I would also like to use Jemalloc for better memory management when running node. I have used this Jemalloc buildpack in the past when using normal node dynos (not docker images) and it has worked great:

https://github.com/gaffneyc/heroku-buildpack-jemalloc

If I understand correctly however buildpacks and docker images arent compatible? So this buildpack wont be available from inside my image automatically?

Is there a way to get the buildpack to run inside my image?

If not does anyone know how I might go about installing and using jemalloc in my instance?

Answer (score 1):

I think [Cloud Native Buildpacks](https://buildpacks.io/) are what you're in need of. Cloud Native Buildpacks produce Docker images as output, which means you don't even need a `Dockerfile`.

The `heroku/buildpacks:18` CNB builder image includes the `heroku/nodejs` buildpack. But you'll need to add the jemalloc buildpack manually. Since jemalloc is an old-style buildpack (i.e. not Cloud Naitve), you'll need to use the [CNB shim](http://jkutner.github.io/2020/05/26/cloud-native-buildpacks-shim.html). In this way you can reference the buildpack with this URL:

```
https://buildpack-registry.heroku.com/cnb/gaffneyc/jemalloc
```

All that said, and with the Pack CLI installed, you should be able to run:

```
$ pack build --builder heroku/buildpacks:18 --buildpack heroku/nodejs,https://buildpack-registry.heroku.com/cnb/gaffneyc/jemalloc my app
```

Comment: thanks mate I really appreciate the help, I think you are on the right track, however running: 

```
pack build --publish --builder heroku/buildpacks:18 --buildpack heroku/nodejs,https://buildpack-registry.heroku.com/cnb/gaffneyc/jemalloc heroku18-nodejs-jemalloc
```

Results in error:

```
ERROR: No buildpack groups passed detection.
ERROR: Please check that you are running against the correct path.
ERROR: failed to detect: no buildpacks participating
ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle: failed with status code: 100
```

Comment: make sure you put the `https://` in front of the `https://buildpack-registry.heroku.com/cnb/gaffneyc/jemalloc` URL

Comment: Does the directory you're running the command in have a `package.json`?

Comment: I not sure. I actually found a different way to solve this issue in the end by simply adding jemalloc into my docker image: https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/mikeysee/battletabs